# Ruby, weird substitution

Tags: ruby, regex

For example:

```
str1 = "pppp(m)pppp"
str2 = "(m)"
str1 = str1.sub(/#{str2}/, "<>#{str2}<>")
```

I will got this:

```
"pppp(<>(m)<>)pppp"
```

I expected to get this:

```
"pppp<>(m)<>pppp"
```

Why it's happening and how to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `(` and `)` have a special meaning in regexen and do not actually match the characters `(` and `)`. The regex `/(m)/` will match any `m` whether or not it is enclosed in parentheses (and if it is, it won't match the parentheses).

To match literal parentheses use `\(` and `\)` - or in a case like this where you're interpolating a string, you can just use `Regexp.escape` on the string, i.e. `/#{ Regexp.escape(str2) }/`.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression is viewing the `"(m)"` as a capture group because the parenthesis are operators in regular expressions to get a literal `"(m)"` you need to use the escape char `\` [`"\(m\)"`].